# Unable to perform A full Farm Backup

Tags: 2013, powershell, sql-server, backup, farm

I have SharePoint 2013 server, containing one web application and three site collections.

I want to perform my first full farm backup, so I wrote the following command inside SharePoint PowerShell:

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory C:\Backup -BackupMethod full -BackupThreads 10 -Force
```

After around 1 hours I got the following exception:
[image]

Here is the related logs, where there are many SQL exceptions:

```
> 21/10/2014 17:42:39] Verbose: Starting object: SharePoint - 80.
> [21/10/2014 17:42:40] Progress: [Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web
> Application] 20 percent complete. [21/10/2014 17:42:40] Verbose:
> [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] SQL Server Connection
> String: Data Source=TGVSQL02\SPS;Initial
> Catalog=StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69;Integrated
> Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool
> Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application
> Name=SharePoint[powershell][1][StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69].
> [21/10/2014 17:42:41] Verbose: Starting object: SharePoint - 80.
> [21/10/2014 17:42:41] Verbose:
> [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] SQL command started
> at: 21/10/2014 17:42:40. This command may take a while to complete and
> without notification. [21/10/2014 17:42:41] Verbose: Starting object:
> WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8. [21/10/2014 17:42:41]
> Verbose: [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] SQL Server
> Command: BACKUP DATABASE
> [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] TO DISK=@db_loc WITH
> NAME=@db_name, STATS=5, NOINIT, NOSKIP, NOFORMAT, NOREWIND 
>   @db_name=StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69,
> @db_loc=C:\FarmBackUp\spbr0000\000000AE.bak [21/10/2014 17:42:41]
> Progress: [SharePoint - 80] 50 percent complete. [21/10/2014 17:42:41]
> Verbose: [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] SQL command
> timeout is set to 1.00 hours. [21/10/2014 17:42:42] Progress:
> [SharePoint - 80] 50 percent complete. [21/10/2014 17:42:42] Warning:
> [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] Cannot open backup
> device 'C:\FarmBackUp\spbr0000\000000AE.bak'. Operating system error
> 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105). BACKUP
> DATABASE is terminating abnormally. [21/10/2014 17:42:42] Verbose:
> Starting object: job-workflow-failover. [21/10/2014 17:42:42]
> Progress: [Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application] 80 percent
> complete. [21/10/2014 17:42:42] Debug:
> [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69]    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
> RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
> ds)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
> Boolean asyncWrite)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior, String method)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Backup.SPSqlBackupRestoreHelper.RunCommand(SqlCommand
> sqlCommand, SPBackupRestoreInformation args, Boolean throwOnRestart,
> Boolean& restart, SPSqlBackupRestoreConnection connection) [21/10/2014
> 17:42:42] Verbose: Starting object: ExpirationProcessing. [21/10/2014
> 17:42:43] Warning: [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] SQL
> command failed and needs to be restarted. The command will be
> re-started a total of three times before throwing an exception.
> [21/10/2014 17:42:43] Verbose:
> [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Connection
> String: Data Source=TGVSQL02\SPS;Initial
> Catalog=WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8;Integrated
> Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool
> Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application
> Name=SharePoint[powershell][1][WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8].
> [21/10/2014 17:42:43] Progress: [job-workflow-failover] 50 percent
> complete. [21/10/2014 17:42:43] Progress: [ExpirationProcessing] 50
> percent complete. [21/10/2014 17:42:44] Verbose:
> [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Command: 
> USE [master] IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE
> name=@db_name) BEGIN
>      SELECT sum(convert(float,size)) * (8192.0) from [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8].dbo.sysfiles END ELSE
> BEGIN
>     SELECT 0 END [21/10/2014 17:42:44] Verbose: Starting object: SchedulingUnpublish. [21/10/2014 17:42:44] Verbose: Starting object:
> job-solution-daily-resource-usage. [21/10/2014 17:42:44] Verbose:
> [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Connection
> String: Data Source=TGVSQL02\SPS;Initial
> Catalog=WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8;Integrated
> Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool
> Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application
> Name=SharePoint[powershell][1][WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8].
> [21/10/2014 17:42:44] Progress: [SchedulingUnpublish] 50 percent
> complete. [21/10/2014 17:42:45] Verbose:
> [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command started at:
> 21/10/2014 17:42:44. This command may take a while to complete and
> without notification. [21/10/2014 17:42:45] Verbose: Starting object:
> SearchAndProcess. [21/10/2014 17:42:45] Progress:
> [job-solution-daily-resource-usage] 50 percent complete. [21/10/2014
> 17:42:45] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL
> Server Command: BACKUP DATABASE
> [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] TO DISK=@db_loc WITH
> NAME=@db_name, STATS=5, NOINIT, NOSKIP, NOFORMAT, NOREWIND 
>   @db_name=WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8,
> @db_loc=C:\FarmBackUp\spbr0000\000000AF.bak [21/10/2014 17:42:45]
> Verbose: Starting object: EducationBulkOperationJob. [21/10/2014
> 17:42:45] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL
> command timeout is set to 1.00 hours. [21/10/2014 17:42:46] Progress:
> [SearchAndProcess] 50 percent complete. [21/10/2014 17:42:46] Warning:
> [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] Cannot open backup
> device 'C:\FarmBackUp\spbr0000\000000AF.bak'. Operating system error
> 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105). BACKUP
> DATABASE is terminating abnormally. [21/10/2014 17:42:46] Verbose:
> Starting object: DocIdEnable. [21/10/2014 17:42:46] Debug:
> [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8]    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
> RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
> ds)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
> Boolean asyncWrite)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior, String method)    at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Backup.SPSqlBackupRestoreHelper.RunCommand(SqlCommand
> sqlCommand, SPBackupRestoreInformation args, Boolean throwOnRestart,
> Boolean& restart, SPSqlBackupRestoreConnection connection) [21/10/2014
> 17:42:46] Progress: [EducationBulkOperationJob] 50 percent complete.
> [21/10/2014 17:42:46] Verbose: Starting object: DocIdAssignment.
> [21/10/2014 17:42:47] Warning:
> [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command failed and
> needs to be restarted. The command will be re-started a total of three
> times before throwing an exception. [21/10/2014 17:42:47] Verbose:
> Starting object: VideoQueryRuleProvisioner. [21/10/2014 17:42:47]
> Progress: [DocIdEnable] 50 percent complete. [21/10/2014 17:42:48]
> Progress: [DocIdAssignment] 50 percent complete. [21/10/2014 17:42:48]
> Verbose: Starting object: job-audit-log-trimming. [21/10/2014
> 17:42:48] Progress: [VideoQueryRuleProvisioner] 50 percent complete.
> [21/10/2014 17:42:48] Verbose: Starting object: BulkWorkflow.
> 
> 
> [21/10/2014 17:57:34] Finished with 102 warnings. [21/10/2014
> 17:57:34] Finished with 25 errors. [21/10/2014 17:57:34] FatalError:
> Backup failed for Object Crawl-0 (C: on TGVSPS01) failed in event
> OnBackupComplete. For more information, see the spbackup.log or
> sprestore.log file located in the backup directory. [21/10/2014
> 17:57:34] -------------------------------------------------
```

can any one advice on this please?

**EDIT**
ok thanks for the reply, i specified a network path, but still i will get these errors :-

```
22/10/2014 12:15:26] Verbose: Starting object: crawler.
[22/10/2014 12:15:26] Debug: [SharePoint_Config]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Backup.SPSqlBackupRestoreHelper.RunCommand(SqlCommand sqlCommand, SPBackupRestoreInformation args, Boolean throwOnRestart, Boolean& restart, SPSqlBackupRestoreConnection connection)
[22/10/2014 12:15:26] Verbose: Starting object: googlebot.
[22/10/2014 12:15:26] Warning: [SharePoint_Config] SQL command failed and needs to be restarted. The command will be re-started a total of three times before throwing an exception.
[22/10/2014 12:15:27] Verbose: Starting object: ms search.
[22/10/2014 12:15:27] Verbose: Starting object: msnbot.
[22/10/2014 12:15:28] Verbose: Starting object: msoffice.
[22/10/2014 12:15:29] Verbose: Starting object: slurp.
[22/10/2014 12:15:30] Verbose: Starting object: License to Feature Mappings.
[22/10/2014 12:15:30] Verbose: Starting object: SharePoint Server State Service.
[22/10/2014 12:15:31] Verbose: Starting object: State Service.
[22/10/2014 12:15:32] Progress: [License to Feature Mappings] 50 percent complete.
[22/10/2014 12:15:32] Verbose: Starting object: StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69.
[22/10/2014 12:15:32] Verbose: Starting object: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application.
[22/10/2014 12:15:33] Verbose: Starting object: SharePoint - 80.
[22/10/2014 12:15:34] Verbose: [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] SQL Server Connection String: Data Source=TGVSQL02\SPS;Initial Catalog=StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[powershell][1][StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69].
[22/10/2014 12:15:34] Verbose: Starting object: SharePoint - 80.
[22/10/2014 12:15:34] Progress: [Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application] 20 percent complete.
[22/10/2014 12:15:34] Verbose: [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] SQL Server Command: 
USE [master]
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name=@db_name)
BEGIN
     SELECT sum(convert(float,size)) * (8192.0) from [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69].dbo.sysfiles
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 0
END
[22/10/2014 12:15:35] Verbose: Starting object: WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8.
[22/10/2014 12:15:35] Verbose: [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] SQL Server Connection String: Data Source=TGVSQL02\SPS;Initial Catalog=StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[powershell][1][StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69].
[22/10/2014 12:15:35] Progress: [SharePoint - 80] 50 percent complete.
[22/10/2014 12:15:35] Progress: [Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application] 80 percent complete.
[22/10/2014 12:15:35] Verbose: Starting object: job-workflow-failover.
[22/10/2014 12:15:36] Progress: [SharePoint - 80] 50 percent complete.
[22/10/2014 12:15:36] Verbose: [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] SQL command started at: 22/10/2014 12:15:35. This command may take a while to complete and without notification.
[22/10/2014 12:15:36] Verbose: Starting object: ExpirationProcessing.
[22/10/2014 12:15:37] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Connection String: Data Source=TGVSQL02\SPS;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[powershell][1][WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8].
[22/10/2014 12:15:37] Verbose: [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] SQL Server Command: BACKUP DATABASE [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] TO DISK=@db_loc WITH NAME=@db_name, STATS=5, NOINIT, NOSKIP, NOFORMAT, NOREWIND 
    @db_name=StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69, @db_loc=\\Tgvfile01.ad-Tgroup.intra\departments\TGroupIntranet\spbr0000\000000AE.bak
[22/10/2014 12:15:37] Progress: [job-workflow-failover] 50 percent complete.
[22/10/2014 12:15:37] Verbose: Starting object: SchedulingUnpublish.
[22/10/2014 12:15:38] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Command: 
USE [master]
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name=@db_name)
BEGIN
     SELECT sum(convert(float,size)) * (8192.0) from [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8].dbo.sysfiles
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 0
END
[22/10/2014 12:15:38] Verbose: [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] SQL command timeout is set to 1.00 hours.
[22/10/2014 12:15:38] Progress: [ExpirationProcessing] 50 percent complete.
[22/10/2014 12:15:38] Verbose: Starting object: job-solution-daily-resource-usage.
[22/10/2014 12:15:39] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Connection String: Data Source=TGVSQL02\SPS;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[powershell][1][WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8].
[22/10/2014 12:15:39] Warning: [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] Cannot open backup device '\\Tgvfile01.ad-Tgroup.intra\departments\TGroupIntranet\spbr0000\000000AE.bak'. Operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
[22/10/2014 12:15:39] Progress: [SchedulingUnpublish] 50 percent complete.
[22/10/2014 12:15:39] Verbose: Starting object: SearchAndProcess.
[22/10/2014 12:15:39] Debug: [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Backup.SPSqlBackupRestoreHelper.RunCommand(SqlCommand sqlCommand, SPBackupRestoreInformation args, Boolean throwOnRestart, Boolean& restart, SPSqlBackupRestoreConnection connection)
[22/10/2014 12:15:39] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command started at: 22/10/2014 12:15:39. This command may take a while to complete and without notification.
[22/10/2014 12:15:39] Progress: [job-solution-daily-resource-usage] 50 percent complete.
[22/10/2014 12:15:40] Verbose: Starting object: EducationBulkOperationJob.
[22/10/2014 12:15:40] Warning: [StateService_002fdb8ee063471b8aba282d26a40e69] SQL command failed and needs to be restarted. The command will be re-started a total of three times before throwing an exception.
[22/10/2014 12:15:40] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL Server Command: BACKUP DATABASE [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] TO DISK=@db_loc WITH NAME=@db_name, STATS=5, NOINIT, NOSKIP, NOFORMAT, NOREWIND 
    @db_name=WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8, @db_loc=\\Tgvfile01.ad-Tgroup.intra\departments\TGroupIntranet\spbr0000\000000AF.bak
[22/10/2014 12:15:40] Progress: [SearchAndProcess] 50 percent complete.
[22/10/2014 12:15:40] Verbose: Starting object: DocIdEnable.
[22/10/2014 12:15:41] Verbose: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] SQL command timeout is set to 1.00 hours.
[22/10/2014 12:15:41] Progress: [EducationBulkOperationJob] 50 percent complete.
[22/10/2014 12:15:42] Verbose: Starting object: DocIdAssignment.
[22/10/2014 12:15:42] Warning: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8] Cannot open backup device '\\Tgvfile01.ad-Tgroup.intra\departments\TGroupIntranet\spbr0000\000000AF.bak'. Operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
[22/10/2014 12:15:42] Verbose: [SharePoint_Config] Retrying to connect to SQL.
[22/10/2014 12:15:42] Progress: [DocIdEnable] 50 percent complete.
[22/10/2014 12:15:43] Verbose: Starting object: VideoQueryRuleProvisioner.
[22/10/2014 12:15:43] Debug: [WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8]    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
```

Comment: Make sure SharePoint Farm admin account, Account which is running Backup, SQL Server Services Account have the Modify rights on the Network Share drive path.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0f84564a-4a99-4999-b8a9-78041cf80a52/sharepoint-foundation-error-when-performing-a-farm-backup?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Backup-SPFarm command should use a network share where The service accounts, Farm accounts and SQL Server service accounts have Full Control access to the share. This is because SharePoint uses SQL commands for running parts of the backup and these execute in SQL Server's context.

More information:
[Prepare to back up and restore farms in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806332(v=office.15).aspx)
[Back up service applications in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428318(v=office.15).aspx)
[Reminder: Use a UNC path as the destination for the Backup-SPFarm cmdlet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexsearch/archive/2014/02/06/reminder-to-use-a-unc-path-for-the-destination-directory-for-the-backup-spfarm-cmdlet.aspx)

Comment: i am storing the backup file on the SharePoint server locally,, so you mean that the sql server can not access the folder inside the sharepoint server ?

Comment: Also i usually do site collection backups in the same way where i store the generated backup files inside the SharePoint server,,, or farm backup is different..?

Comment: Farm backup behaves differently and each database is backed up to a separate file. You can store it local to the server, but you should pass a network path instead of a local path.
Found this [other reference](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexsearch/archive/2014/02/06/reminder-to-use-a-unc-path-for-the-destination-directory-for-the-backup-spfarm-cmdlet.aspx)

Comment: ok i define a network path ,, but still i am getting exceptions, an u please check my original question as i have added the new logs which contains the exception i am getting . thanks.

Comment: Did you configure the permission for the SQL Server service account?

Comment: i solve this by creating a new network share on the sharepoint server (locally), and i specify the directory to target it , and the farm back up finishes successfully.but i have noted something , i run the farm backup twice. the first backup file size was 787 MB , while the second farm backup file was 747 MB, so there is around 30MB differences, and ofcourse no data was removed or added during the two runs ,but the total number of file is the same 194 files ?? so does this raise any concerns ?

Comment: I wouldn't worry much. It is probably because some log files were cleaned out in the SQL server in between the backups.